# Using PHP Curl to display JSON API data; can I use Javascript instead?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, curl

I have been working on displaying JSON API data (the API I am using is found at openweathermap.org) on an HTML webpage, and have had success.  I wrote PHP script to retrieve JSON data from the source and displayed it on my page using PHP Curl.

Here is my PHP code (I took out my API key for openweathermap)

```
<?php
$apiKey = "";
$cityId = "5007402";
$googleApiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=" . $cityId . "&lang=en&units=imperial&APPID=" . $apiKey;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $googleApiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($response);
$currentTime = time();
?>
```

And here is the section of my HTML code used to display said information;

```
<div class="report-container">
        <h2><?php echo $data->name; ?> Weather Status</h2>
        <div class="time">
            <div><?php echo date("l g:i a", $currentTime); ?></div>
            <div><?php echo date("jS F, Y",$currentTime); ?></div>
            <div><?php echo ucwords($data->weather[0]->description); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="weather-forecast">
            <img
                src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/<?php echo $data->weather[0]->icon; ?>.png"
                class="weather-icon" /> <?php echo $data->main->temp_max; ?>&deg;C<span
                class="min-temperature"><?php echo $data->main->temp_min; ?>&deg;C</span>
        </div>
        <div class="time">
            <div>Humidity: <?php echo $data->main->humidity; ?> %</div>
            <div>Wind: <?php echo $data->wind->speed; ?> km/h</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, what I have is working, but I would like to know if anyone could help me achieve the same output, but by using Javascript. I have some experience with PHP/HTML/CSS/MYsql, but I have none with javascript. This is the end I am hoping to achieve;

1. PHP script retrieving JSON data from source
2. Write JavaScript to retrieve the JSON data from the PHP script and display on page

Can anyone help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you can start with.

`my_api_data.php`

```
<?php
$apiKey = "";
$cityId = "5007402";
$googleApiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=" . $cityId . "&lang=en&units=imperial&APPID=" . $apiKey;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $googleApiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

```js
// Javascript Code

fetch('https://example.org/my_api_data.php')
 .then(r => r.json())
 .then(data => {
    const myData = JSON.parse(data);
    const myHTML = `
      <div class="report-container">
        <h2>${myData['name']} Weather Status</h2>
        <div class="time">
            <div>${new Date().toLocaleString()}</div>
            <div>${myData['weather'][0]['description']}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="time">
            <div>Humidity: ${myData['main']['humidity']} %</div>
            <div>Wind: ${myData['wind']['speed']} km/h</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;

    document.write(myHTML);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @brybry44 Please consider accepting this as the answer if this helped.